# Value of the model includes unnecessary text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does the `itemsPerPage` model get assigned the value of `5 per page` if I specify `{{item}} per page` inside the **option** tag?

```
<!-- the normal case: itemsPerPage is 5, 10, 20 -->
<select ng-model="itemsPerPage" ng-init="items = [5, 10, 20]">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</option>
</select>

<!-- the odd case: itemsPerPage is 5 per page, 10 per page, 20 per page -->
<select ng-model="itemsPerPage" ng-init="items = [5, 10, 20]">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} per page</option>
</select>
```

Comment: read specs on select tag, has nothing to do with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not assign value attribute for option tags, in that case value will be all text inside open and close selected 'option' tag, use 'ng-options' directive for build select optons

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Example:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Select "Three" and select value will be "3" as this option has value attribute and it is "3"

```
<select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Select "Three" and select value will be "Three" as this option has no value and select will get as value text inside

You'r first and second examples are the same, without value attribute. difference only in text inside .

If you use ng-options angular directive it will build select correct

```
<select ng-model="selItem" ng-init="items = [{id: 1, name: 'One'},{id: 2, name: 'Two'},{id: 3, name: 'Three'}]" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
</select>
```

look this http://jsfiddle.net/em3f8t9r/2/

Comment: could you expand your answer with small example please?

Comment: sorry jsfiddle link was broken

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

I use

```
<select ng-model="itemsPerPage" ng-options="'show ' + item + ' items' for item in [5, 10, 25]" class="left"></select>
```

with

```
$scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
```

assigned in the corresponding controller;